# Injection of HttpServletRequest in GWTP ActionHandler using Spring

Tags: spring, gwt, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, gwt-platform

I have implemented my GWT application using Spring + GWTP.

I want to access HttpServletRequest object into my ActionHandler class.

The ServerModule is Spring Configuration class (using @Configuration Annotation).

Now problem is how can I inject the current HttpServletRequest, ServletContext, ServletConfig in my ActionHandler using Spring.

Following is the definition of ServerModule:

```
@Configuration   
@Import(DefaultModule.class)    
public class ServerModule extends HandlerModule
{
   @Bean
   public UserVerficationActionHandler getUserVerificationActionActionHandler()
   {
      return new UserVerficationActionHandler();
   }
}
```

In above Example I just want to inject the HttpServletRequest using Spring.

Any guidance on this highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems I have to work it out using HttpSessionListener and Filter. Though it would be nice if I can inject request object using Spring DI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RequestProvider is your solution. It's a class in gwt-dispatch-server jar.

DefaultModule provides the RequestProvider bean so that you can just inject it into places you need it.

Take a look at the sourcec code for com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.spring.configuration.DefaultModule which creates the RequestProvider as a DefaultRequestProvider which then defers to [RequestContextHolder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html) to do the work.

See the link for what you need to add to your web.xml to get this to work.